# Change D3 scatter plot x-axis to logarithmic

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

If I have the following chart, how do I make x-axis a logarithmic scale?
https://jsfiddle.net/1p4wm84m/14/

```
[x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w])]
```

If I change the above code to log(), the x-axis doesn't render correctly.

```
[x = d3.scale.log().range([0, w])]
```

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, that jsfiddle isn't rendering... can you check your fiddle again and make sure it renders?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1p4wm84m/20/ Let's try the URL without the https

Comment: You can't have a 0 with a log scale -- make it a very small value close to 0, e.g. 1e-6.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you! Any thoughts on how to best format the axis now?